# Resource conflicts and AppScript created Google Calendar events

Tags: resources, google-calendar-api, invite

I have a Form -> Spreadsheet -> Calendar process set up so that members of our organisation can book resources for events. The form/spreadsheet/calendars/scripts are all owned by an unattended domain account.

Ideally the process would create the event in another domain account so that declined resource invitations would be sent to the person making the booking however, I haven't found a way to do this from my day of googling.

My initial implementation had events being created and conflicts noticed with a declined invitation being sent to the unattended account. That was all good.  I then wanted to survey the invited resources to identify which had declined so that I could email a list of such to the person making the booking however, all the resources returned a responseStatus of "needsAction" irrespective of whether there was a conflict or not.

After some googling a discusion somewhere (might have been in stackoverflow) suggested creating the event while supplying a responseStatus of "Accepted" for each of the resources.  It did not say so in that discussion but I assumed that the expectation was that the status would be updated if there was a conflict.  Turns out that is not the case as multiple overlapping events involving the same resources now all show the resource as being accepted.

I am pretty sure my domain Calendar settings are correct, based on visual inspection of the settings and the observed initial implementation behaviour, but I stand ready to be corrected.

Looking to hear about people experiences in this area.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is not to force the acceptance, and then just be patient for the system to process the accept/decline of resources.  I put a 15 second sleep into the process between creating the event and re-querying to check on resource status.